# Bathroom Drywall: Protect walls behind faucet sink from water damage

Tags: bathroom, water, drywall, waterproofing

I installed a new vanity which comes with backsplash 4 inch high. Currently it has a 2 inch space gap below, between the mirror and the backsplash.

(a) What is a good product to fill in the space, so it does not damage the drywall behind? (trying to prevent water damage and mold etc).

(b) Or is the optimal solution to just move the mirror down 2 inches? If so, Is there a still a possibility water can leak between edges of mirror and backsplash?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint will protect that 2” strip from splashes. Be sure to wipe those splashes off after they happen.

If you don’t already have it, a bead of caulking across the top of the backsplash will prevent water getting behind. You could choose silicone (durable, but can’t be painted) or a hybrid kitchen/bath that’s paintable. I’d always choose paintable, personally.

If you choose to move the mirror (I wouldn’t), be sure to caulk the joint between the mirror and the backsplash.

Comment: one more follow up question, on the Left side wall of the faucet sink, we have a smaller height mirror with same 4 inch backsplash, so there is 10 inches of drywall space gap. Will 10 inch height paint still prevent this issue? then what is the point of backsplash? (just decorative?) thanks again !

Comment: @mattsmith5 I have a similar setup with a 10 inch gap and it's been fine for the last 7 years. I only wipe major splashes. And do seal the top of the backsplash as suggested, this is critical. Also be aware that latex paint will get damaged by water for at least 2 weeks even though it feels dry. Possibly longer for darker colors. I'd put a piece of cardboard in front for about a month to be on the safe side. And then install the backsplash permanently.

Comment: thanks, so second question is what is point of backsplash, if paint is sufficient?

Comment: The backsplash itself catches major splashes, typically only small amounts of water get above it. That said, some folks don’t have backsplashes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Water resistant paint is easiest, but not so good overtime. Use two or more coats. it might look cheap, because mirror sticking out.

Next would be strip of vinyl (or metal plate) glued and caulked (not my favorite) but good water resistance.

Most decorative and permanent would be mosaic tiles.

They will cover the depth between mirror sticking out and make it look good. If you extend them beyond mirror with (counter with).

The choices are endless.